# How can I make my factorial method work with decimals? (Gamma)

Tags: java, math

I have a method that returns the factorial of the input. It works perfectly for integers, but I cant figure out how to make it work with decimal numbers.

Here is my method currently:

```
public static double factorial(double d)
{
    if (d == 0.0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    double abs = Math.abs(d);
    double decimal = abs - Math.floor(abs);
    double result = 1.0;

    for (double i = Math.floor(abs); i > decimal; --i)
    {
        result *= (i + decimal);
    }
    if (d < 0.0)
    {
        result = -result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I found an implementation but the code wasn't shown (I lost the link) and the example given was `5.5! = 5.5 * 4.5 * 3.5 * 2.5 * 1.5*0.5! = 287.885278`

So from this pattern, I just added the decimal value to `i` in the for-loop `result *= (i + decimal)`

But clearly my logic is flawed

Edit: Just realsed that the last value is 0.5!, not 0.5. This makes all the difference. So `0.5! = 0.88622` and `5.5!` = `5.5 * 4.5 * 3.5 * 2.5 * 1.5 * 0.88622` which equals `287.883028125`

Comment: So what does your implementation give, and what have you done to diagnose what's happening?

Comment: With "floating point version of the factorial" the Gamma function might be meant. A totally different approach. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument

Comment: It is not the logic in your code that is flawed. What is flawed is your assumption that the factorial method is supposed to have a meaning on decimals. But that method is defined to work for whole positive numbers; and nothing else.

Comment: According to that interpretation, `5.001! = 5.001 * 4.001 * 3.001 * 2.001 * 1.001 * 0.001 = 0.1202` - kind of surpising; expected `5.001! > 5!`

Comment: hmm... okay, that makes sense. I guess the logic is completely wrong then.

Comment: @tucuxi Actually, the the last value isn't 0.001, it is 0.001! which, for your example, results in 120.153726 instead of 0.1202. Looks like I missed this too in my code.

Comment: @NervezXx true - I missed the trailing `!`. Although, to be strict, those `!` should have been `Γ`s

Comment: Factorials don't work that way.  You need the gamma function: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html.  gamma(n) = (n-1)!   It accepts decimal input values.  Implement that or find a library that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (which generalizes factorials to real numbers) is rather tricky to implement directly. Use a library such as [apache-commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html#gamma%28double%29) to calculate it for you, or [look at their source](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/special/Gamma.java;h=aa0e90c23271054ae31ddab525bc392f01feb263;hb=refs/heads/master#l655) to get a feel of what is involved. Once available, use as follows:

```
public static double generalizedFactorial(double d) {
    // Gamma(n) = (n-1)! for integer n
    return Gamma.gamma(d+1);
}
```

Outputs:

```
4.0! = 24.0
5.5! = 287.88527781504433
6.0! = 720.0
```

**Previous answer** (*provides a factorial-like interpretation for real numbers > 1; but since there is already an aggreed-upon extension of factorial to real numbers, please **disregard** this for anything practical*):

```
public static double f(double d) {
    double r = d - Math.floor(d) + 1;
    for (;d>1; d-=1) {
        r *= d;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Outputs:

```
4.0! = 24.0
5.5! = 487.265625
6.0! = 720.0
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting, could you explain the math behind this a bit more? Also, google calculator outputs different values for the decimals. For example, 3.5! in google calculator is 11.6317283966 and your code outputs 19.6875.

Comment: This does not implement the gamma function (where `G(n) = (n-1)!` for integer `n`) - instead, it is a kludge to get `f(n) = n!` for integers and `f(r1) < f(r2)` for `1 < r1 < r2`. If you need the actual gamma function for google-completeness, use a library - for example, [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html#gamma%28double%29).

Answer (score 4):

Factorial isn't actually defined for x€R, only for x€N. In words: you can't calculate the factorial of a decimal. (You can for 5.0, but not 5.1)

Edit: Thats the view for "traditional" factorial, for (really rarely needed) decimal factorial, see "gamma function".

Comment: So it is not possible at all? how come google calculator gives a result when you input 3.2! for example? Surely if it was impossible, the result would be "Error". -Edit: Okay, I hadn't heard about the `gamma function` before... I guess this would be what google calculator uses.

Comment: Well, you can see this as two different "factorials", 1 is the traditional function, that is usually needed (eg combinatorics) and that is not defined for decimals. The thing you would need if you really wanted to do it is called "gamma function". This is advanced stuff though. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: Factorials are defined for doubles; the implementation has nothing to do with the naive integer implementation.  You need to look at the gamma function: gamma(n) = (n-1)!  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for this. All you need is some form of the Summation in calculus. It's explained in this video that I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_HeaeUUOnc

In the formula, N is a value you set. The higher it is, the more accurate your factorial will be.

The formula is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdmTH.png)

There is a java library that implements this, but here is a possible piece of code for the formula.

```java
private double factorialInterpolation(int N, double x) {
        double total = 0d;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            total += Math.log((i / x + i));
        }
        
        total += x * Math.log(N);
        
        return total;
}
    
public double factorial(double x) {
        int N = 10000; // higher values gets more accuracy
        
        return Math.exp(factorialInterpolation(N, x));
}
```